# Question relating to the student test

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

$S$ = sample standard deviation

I am not sure what the value for $\mu$ should be since we are trying to calculate $P({X}<1500)$, right? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Again you removed data :( . At least you include n and s. these are required. I had removed the comment because you added it back.

Comment: Also , you removed mu now, Without given mu. You can't calculate P(Xbar < 1500) . Also why wrote X instead of Xbar.  What are you doing????

Answer (score 0):

$t = \frac{(\bar{X} - \mu)}{\frac{s}{\sqrt(n)}}$
with df = n-1

here
s =   $1319.5852$
hence
$P(\mu- \bar{X} < 1500)$
$= P(\bar{X} - \mu > -1500)$
$=P(t > (\frac{-1500}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}})$
$=P(t >  \frac{-1500}{\frac{1319.585}{\sqrt{5}}}$
$= P(t > -2.5417)$
$= 0.9681$

Comment: can you explain the line
$$P(t > (\frac{-1500}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}})$$ and how it follows from the previous line?

Comment: this is because t = (Xbar - mu)/(s/sqrt(n)).  just divide by (s/sqrt(n)) on both sides to get t on left side of inequality and -1500/((s/sqrt(n)) on right side

Comment: Note that you can also use (W - n mu)/(s* sqrt(n))  as mentioned in question. then write Xbar as W/5 and proceed to use t-distribution with W.